# "Pursue my goals" vs "reach my goals"

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it correct to say so? For instance,

> I like to **pursue my goals** wholeheartedly

Or maybe *reach my goals* would be better?

Answer (score 5):

Both *pursue* and *reach* are grammatically correct, but they mean different things and have to be used a little differently.

To *[pursue](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pursue)* something is to chase or follow it, usually with the intent of catching it, either literally or metaphorically.

> The dog **pursued** the rabbit. (meaning the dog *chased* the rabbit)
>
> We are **pursuing** a global strategy. (meaning we are *following* a strategy that includes the entire world)

To *[reach](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reach)* something, in this kind of usage, means to get arrive at it, or to achieve it.

> The swimmer **reached** the island. (meaning the swimmer *swam all the way* to the island)
>
> The monk **reached** enlightenment by meditating. (meaning the monk *achieved* enlightenment through meditation)

To say "I like to pursue my goals wholeheartedly" makes sense grammatically and syntactically; it means "I like to chase my objectives with complete devotion."  To say "I like to reach my goals wholeheartedly" is grammatically correct, but sounds very strange and doesn't make a lot of sense.  Of course you like to achieve your goals - isn't the whole point of a goal that it's something that you want?  And how do you *obtain something with complete devotion*?  You either obtain it or you don't.

The thing that might make *reach* slightly confusing is the phrasal verb *[reach for](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/reach+for)*, which means to extend your grasp for something (again, either literally or metaphorically) but not necessarily to actually obtain it!

> "What time is it?", I said, **reaching for** my watch.  (meaning that I extended my arm to grasp my watch, and presumably did grasp it)
>
> He **reached for** words to explain himself, but could find none.  (meaning that he metaphorically grasped for words, but couldn't find anything)

You could say "I enjoy *reaching for* my goals wholeheartedly", since it means "to try to grasp", and not necessarily "to obtain".

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the verbs "pursue" and "rich" is that the former means the process, whereas the latter--the result, the exact meanings of the two being easy to find in any online dictionary.

In your sentence, the adverb "wholeheartedly" appears to be synonymous to "enthusiastically" and it qualifies the actions being carried out to achieve the goal. So "to ***pursue*** my goals wholeheartedly" will be the right choice to make.

As for "to reach ones goal", once it has already been reached, the appropriate adjectives to use would be "finally", "eventually", "easily", "quickly", and so on.